# Shift DC signal to AC

Tags: level-shifting

I want to make a DTMF decoder and use it on an internal DC phone line. I made a decoder with PIC microprocessor ([Black DTMF decoder](http://www.romanblack.com/DTMF/DTMF_alg.htm)) that works with signals around 0V. My internal phone line consists of a 9V battery, a 330 ohm resister and a phone, all in a series circuit and the DTMF signal is read from resistor ends. My problem is that the signal is always above 0V (around 3.5V that changes if I use another phone) and I need to shift it around 0V but I don't know how?

Edited: This is my circuits diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXES0N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJqu9k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Decoupling capacitor for DTMF signal.*

You need to decouple the DTMF signal with a series capacitor. It will block the DC component from reaching the DTMF decoder.

Unfortunately you haven't given a circuit schematic of your setup or any component values so I can't be any more specific.

Comment: I added the circuit diagram.

Comment: So is there still a question?

Comment: Oh, there was a problem with pin direction register. It is now working.